# Filter WP_QUERY by custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to solve one issue with one of the functions which I've created recently. Below you will find a piece of code which creates a dropdown field in which each  represents specific 'partner company'. The code works perfectly.

```
function fnc_select_1() {

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'freecourses',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'status' => 'publish',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'meta_key' => 'validation_date',
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($the_query->have_posts()):

        while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();

                if(have_rows('validation_date')): 
                    while (have_rows('validation_date')) : the_row();  

                    if( get_sub_field('company')) {
                        $firm_array[] = get_sub_field('company');
                    }                                                                                                               

                    endwhile; 

                    wp_reset_query();

                else :
                    // no rows found
                endif;

        endwhile;

        $firms = array_unique($firm_array);
        natsort($firms);

        echo '<select type="text" class="form-control" name="company" id="company">';
          echo '<option value="">company</option>';
        foreach ($firms as $firm) {
            echo '<option value="'. $firm .'">'; 
            echo $firm;                                 
            echo '</option>';                                                   
        }
        echo '</select>';

    endif;  
}
add_shortcode( 'select_1', 'fnc_select_1' );
```

Because of certain reasons I've decided to enhance this function by adding:

- extra filtering based on custom taxonomy (called "type")
- based on a page in which function will be displayed I wanted to limit / filter those companies by specific terms of this taxonomy.

So I've created this kind of code:

```
  if (is_page(29557) ):
        $childno = '205';

    elseif (is_page(29640) ):
        $childno = '206';

    endif;
```

and simply to my wp_query args I thought I may add:

```
'tax_query' => array(     
    'relation' => 'AND',                 
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'type',  
        'child_of' => $childno
      ),
),
```

but it doesn't work. It do not display the dropdown at all..

Where is the issue then?

Comment: Where did you get `child_of` from? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters doesn’t mention any such parameter.

Comment: @04FS - you are right.. my issue. I took it from get_terms.. So do you have an idea how to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: To filter by a term id, use the `terms` parameter. Posts that have terms that are children of the term you are looking for, will automatically be included, if you don’t want that, you can set `include_children` to false.